How to get dso infomations in linux perf call graph?
I want to find in perf's call graph which function of a certain library function is called by the corresponding source code function of the binary file, and get this data for parsing, but the call graph in the perf report Only the symbol can be seen, but I cannot see which dso the symbol comes from, which is not conducive to writing the result to the disk for analysis. What should I do to get more detailed information about the call graph？
perf record command:
perf record -g ./BubbleSort1

perf report command:
perf report -g flat,0.5,callee,function,percent

one of report elements
I know BubbleSort function belongs to my binary, but in this TUI, it doesn't have dso.
In fact, I can press ENTER on BubbleSort to see which dso it belongs to, but I want to write this result to disk and use pandas for analysis, is there any way I can get this information in the file as well?
